# converting to numeric data for decision tree from a matrix?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have some data in a form of numpy array as follows:

```
array([['vhigh', '2', '2', 'small', 'low', 'unacc'],
       ['vhigh', '2', '2', 'small', 'med', 'unacc'],
       ['vhigh', '2', '2', 'small', 'high', 'good']], dtype=object)
```

that is extracted from the car dataset available at:
https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Car+Evaluation

I want to use this data to apply a classification decision tree by using scikit and I managed to convert the first column, or category, into a set of numbers with:

```
y=data[:,0]
y=le.fit_transform(y)
print y
```

because I was getting an error that said:

```
could not convert string to float
```

the problem that I have is when I want to convert the array into one hot encoding. I have done the following:

```
X=data[:,1:]
enc=preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
enc.fit(X)
Xn=enc.transform(X)
Xn=Xn.reshape(-1,1)
ohe=preprocessing.OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
```

and the error I get is:

```
bad input shape (1728L, 6L)
```

What am I doing wrong? or is there another way around to convert from categorical to numeric an array?

Thanks

Comment: I _suppose_ that `le.fit` refers to `scikit.learn`... Could you please be more careful and try to provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the last sklearn version (>20.0) you can just use `OneHotEncoder`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(
    'https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/car/car.data', header=None)
X, y = df.iloc[:,1:] , df.iloc[:,0]
encoded_y = preprocessing.LabelEncoder().fit_transform(y)
```

**`sklearn >= 20.0`:**

```
ohe = preprocessing.OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
encoded_x = ohe.fit_transform(X)

>>> pd.DataFrame(encoded_x, columns=ohe.get_feature_names())
      x0_high  x0_low  x0_med  x0_vhigh  x1_high  x1_low ...
0         0.0     0.0     0.0       1.0      0.0     0.0 ...
1         0.0     0.0     0.0       1.0      0.0     0.0 ...
2         0.0     0.0     0.0       1.0      0.0     0.0 ...
3         0.0     0.0     0.0       1.0      0.0     0.0 ...
4         0.0     0.0     0.0       1.0      0.0     0.0 ...
5         0.0     0.0     0.0       1.0      0.0     0.0 ...
...
```

**`sklearn < 20.0`:**

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
dv = DictVectorizer(sparse=False) 
encoded_x = dv.fit_transform(X.to_dict(orient='records'))
pd.DataFrame(encoded_x, columns=dv.get_feature_names())
```

Fitting a classifier:

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
DecisionTreeClassifier().fit(encoded_x, encoded_y)
```

Comment: thanks @hellpanderr, but I still got the error "could not convert string to float: vgood"

Comment: @Little could you post all the details?

Comment: I have written the same program as you show me, but I still got that the error. I am using Python 2.7 and scikit 0.19

Comment: @Little Sorry I forgot about the difference between sklearn versions, I'll add the solution for 0.19